# Creating Bucket in VBA with string values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a bucket of corresponding regions from string values of country codes. I have written a code using for loop and nested if conditions as below:
Data:

```
Column A.         Column B
Country code.     Region.
```

**Code:**

```
Sub bucket()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 2 To 4321
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "IN" Or Range("A" & i).Value = "CN" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = "ASIA"
            
        ElseIf Range("A" & i).Value = "UK" Or Range("A" & i).Value = "GB" Then
            Range("B" & 1).Value = "EMEA"
        
        ElseIf Range("A" & i).Value = "US" Or Range("A" & i).Value = "CAN" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = "USAI"
        
        Else
            Range("B" & i).Value = "other"
            
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I just wanted to check is there any alternative solution for string buckets in vba.

Comment: Yeah...edited...thanks:)

Comment: @nanuse, I've indented this to show you what Mathieu meant. There was also some incorrect syntax which I've fixed. I wouldn't usually correct code in the question but since you were asking for alternatives to your current code I thought it couldn't hurt

Answer (score 9):

A cleaner alternative would be `Select Case`

```
sub bucket()
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 2 To 4321
    Select Case Range("A" & i)
      Case "IN","CN"
        Range("B" & i).Value = "ASIA"
      Case "UK", "GB"
        Range("B" & i).Value = "EMEA"
      Case "US", "CA"
        Range("B" & i).Value = "USAI"
      Case Else
        Range("B" & i).Value = "other"
    End Select
  Next i
End sub
```

Or to get even fancier:

```
sub bucket()
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 2 To 4321
    With Range("B" & i)
      Select Case UCase$(Range("A" & i).Value)
        Case "IN","CN"
          .Value = "ASIA"
        Case "UK", "GB"
          .Value = "EMEA"
        Case "US", "CA"
          .Value = "USAI"
        Case Else
          .Value = "other"
      End Select
    End With
  Next

End sub
```

These differences make it easier to read, easier to add more options later, and easier to modify if the columns were to change later.

Comment: The second one maybe faster.

Comment: Making it a UDF would be even better/faster.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative with `Switch()` function:

```
Sub bucket()
    Dim i As Long        
    Dim str As String
    Dim var As Variant

    For i = 2 To 4321
        str = UCase$(Cells(i, 1).Value)
        var = Switch(str = "IN", "ASIA", str = "UK", "EMEA", str = "US", "USAI", _
                     str = "CN", "ASIA", str = "GB", "EMEA", str = "CA", "USAI")
        If IsNull(var) Then var = "other"
        Cells(i, 2).Value = var
    Next
End Sub
```

Or another one with no loops:

```
Sub bucket()
    With Range("B2:B4321")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-1]=""IN"",RC[-1]=""CN""),""ASIA"",   IF(OR(RC[-1]=""UK"",RC[-1]=""GB""),""EMEA"",  IF(OR(RC[-1]=""US"",RC[-1]=""CA""),""USAI"",""other"")))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

which can also be written as follows:

```
Sub bucket()
    With Range("B2:B4321")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-1]=""IN"",RC[-1]=""CN""),""ASIA""," & _
                        "IF(OR(RC[-1]=""UK"",RC[-1]=""GB""),""EMEA""," & _
                        "IF(OR(RC[-1]=""US"",RC[-1]=""CA""),""USAI""," & _
                        """other"")))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's pretty cool - harder to read IMO, but still great shorthand.

Comment: @braX, well the indentation in the 1st and 3rd code has the precise goal to make it (nearly) as readable as `Select Case`

Comment: Yes, and it works great for this example, and it's probably faster. If there were multiple instructions for each case tho, instead of just a string getting returned/added, I'm guessing `Switch` probably wouldn't help. I still think it's great to learn new ways of doing things like this tho. Thanks.

Comment: @braX, _"If there were multiple instructions for each case tho…I'm guessing Switch probably wouldn't help"_, but that was not the OP case I'm answering to...

Comment: I understand. I am not saying it was bad, I was the one to vote you up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option, using `Scripting.Dictionary`. It's probably as close to a "bucket" as you'll get in VBA. It stores key-value pairs and returns them quickly.

I pulled out the population of the dictionary into a separate function -- while not strictly necessary, it makes it easier to update the items in your dictionary in future.

```
Sub MapContinents()
    Dim d As Object, inputRange As Range, r As Range
    
    Set inputRange = Sheet1.Range("A2:A4321")
    Set d = GetContinentMapping
    
    For Each r In inputRange
        If d.Exists(r.Value) Then
            r.Offset(, 1).Value = d(r.Value)
        Else
            r.Offset(, 1).Value = "Other"
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetContinentMapping()
    Dim d As Object
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    d.Add "IN", "ASIA"
    d.Add "CN", "ASIA"
    d.Add "UK", "EMEA"
    d.Add "GB", "EMEA"
    d.Add "USA", "USAI"
    d.Add "CAN", "USAI"
    
    Set GetContinentMapping = d
End Function
```

---

Edit: If you wish to use the approach above, but also enjoy speed improvements (see T.M's great suggestions and speed comparisons), you can adapt the code above to use VBA arrays. Replacing the first sub above with the code below will speed up run time considerably. The trade off (imo) is that you lose a bit of readability, but it might be well worth it!

```
Sub MapContinents()
    Dim d As Object
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim inputData As Variant, v As Variant, outputData As Variant, i As Long
    
    Set inputRange = Sheet1.Range("A2:A4321")
    inputData = inputRange.Value
    ReDim outputData(1 To UBound(inputData), 1 To 1)
    Set d = GetContinentMapping
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(inputData)
        If d.Exists(inputData(i, 1)) Then
            outputData(i, 1) = d(inputData(i, 1))
        Else
            outputData(i, 1) = "Other"
        End If
    Next
    
    inputRange.Offset(, 1).Value = outputData
End Sub
```

Comment: A helpful, clear & instructive answer +:) @CallumDa - Fyi You might be interested in my speed comparisons demonstrating some newer dynamic approaches, too.

Comment: @T.M., great job. The LET formula was new to me, so I particularly appreciate you contributing to this question! I'd be interested to know how your speeds fare on my updated code? I'd like to think something as simple as this could be achieved fully in VBA (i.e. without applying formulas to the worksheet) in the blink of an eye, too.

Comment: Thx for response and your interest; my main intention was to introduce the use of `LET`. - Due to your comment I included your edited post (0.03 secs) to speed tests: it reveals to be nearly as fast as `LET` (0.02 secs)! Confirms the statements in sections A) .. E), especially that looping through ranges by means of VBA can be time consuming compared to either the array approach or to the newer dynamic possibilities  (didn't test evaluations yet ).

Answer (score 1):

**Some speed considerations**

- **A.** Looping through a cell range by means of VBA can be time-consuming,
- **B.** it is faster to process an array instead.

---

- **C.** Addressing, however an entire table range *dynamically* with an Excel formula
  can increase the processing speed considerably.

**C.** If you dispose of the newer **dynamic array functions**, it would be sufficient to
insert a single formula (e.g. in cell `B2`) resulting in a so called spill range.

I want to demonstrate especially the `Let()` formula which allows to avoid some redundancies in traditional formulae.
It groups formula variables with their code or value assignments in form of
argument pairs before defining the result logic as last argument eventually.

Note also the use of `Match` applied on two data fields, where `Index(table,,2)`, for example defines the needed
2nd column of the lookup table.

```
    =LET(data,$A$2:$A$4321,table,Sheet2!A$2:A$8,result,INDEX(INDEX(table,,2),MATCH(data,INDEX(table,,1),0)),IF(ISERROR(result),"Other",result))"
```

Of course you might also do this (once) using VBA
(assuming a lookup table e.g. in `Sheet2!A2:A8`):

```
Sub FormulaApproach365()   ' 0.02 secs needed
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Formula2 = _
    "=LET(data,$A$2:$A$4321,table,Sheet2!A$2:A$8,result,INDEX(INDEX(table,,2),MATCH(data,INDEX(table,,1),0)),IF(ISERROR(result),""Other"",result))"
    Debug.Print "Formula approach 365", Format(Timer - t, "0.00 secs needed")
End Sub
```

*Note that you can obtain similar results with `=XLOOKUP(A2:A12,Sheet2!A2:A8,Sheet2!B2:B8,"Other")`, though not as fast*

- **D.** Alternative in dynamic array versions:

```
Sub FormulaApproachDynamic()   ' 0.03 secs needed
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Formula2 = _
    "=IF(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A4321,Sheet2!A2:A8,0)),INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B8,MATCH(A2:A4321,Sheet2!A2:A8,0)),""Other"")"
    Debug.Print "Formula approach DA", Format(Timer - t, "0.00 secs needed")
End Sub
```

- **E.** **More backwards compatible approach**

Instead of this dynamic spill approach in `D.` above you can also apply a `.FormulaArray = ...` assignment
upon the corresponding entire column `B` range (`CSE`, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>).

---

**Time needed**

*Note: This doesn't intend by no means to qualify the mentioned answers, as* **speed** *was* **no** *requirement of the original post!*

| ad) | Approach | Time needed | Post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A.) | Range Loop | 1.23 seconds | [braX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811498/creating-bucket-in-vba-with-string-values/58811547#58811547) |
| B.) | I. Range Loop/dictionary | 0.85 seconds | [CallumDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811498/creating-bucket-in-vba-with-string-values/70924325#70924325) |
| " | II. Array Loop/dictionary | 0.03 seconds | [CallumDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811498/creating-bucket-in-vba-with-string-values/70924325#70924325) - Edit/2022-02-02 |
| C.) | LET Formula365 | **0.02** seconds | see this post |
| D.) | Dynamic Array | 0.03 seconds | " - " |
| E.) | CSE | 0.03 seconds | " - " |

*Doesn't include [DisplayName 's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811498/creating-bucket-in-vba-with-string-values/58813872?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C29.7438#58813872) valid `Switch` approach repeating each condition within the formula, as the formula length may be a serious limit.*

Comment: @CallumDA Edited my post to include your new version to speed tests.